# Trending vs Trendy

Tags: word-usage, semantics

This just randomly popped up in my mind, and I tried to sort out the semantics to myself, and how I would explain it to a foreigner learning English as a second language...and I couldn't.
Some help here?

Comment: "meaning--in fashion at the moment" this is the differentiating bit that stands out to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that **Trending** describes something that is currently popular (or presently trending), whereas **Trendy** more closely conveys something as having the potential for becoming popular.

*This new car is very trendy. Who knows, in a few months it may even be trending.*

Comment: This is about the exact explanation that popped up in my head, but I immediately countered it by thinking: "Trendy fashion" as in, it's already popular